# Outer join in Oracle without using SQL 99 syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

Due to limitations in the framework I am using, I need to do an outer join without using the SQL 99 syntax (`a outer join b on ...`).  If I want one row of output for every row in `companies` whether or not there is a corresponding row in `documents`, how do I write that using the old Oracle outer join syntax?

```
SELECT D.COMPANY_ID, C.COMPANY_ID, D.DOCUMENT_ID, D.DOCUMENT_CODE
  FROM DOCUMENTS D, COMPANIES C
 WHERE D.COMPANY_ID IS NULL OR D.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
```

Comment: I don't understand-- the query you posted is using joins.  Are you saying that you need to use the pre-SQL 99 join syntax rather than the SQL 99 join syntax ('inner join`, `outer join`, etc.) to implement an outer join?

Comment: Yes exactly, better explanation than mine

Comment: Why don't you want to use the (much better) explicit `outer join`? Even Oracle recommends stop using the `(+)` operator.

Comment: I would if I could, also think is a better idea, but I have to stick with the framework I'm using:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need outer join, you can use special oracle syntax for that (+)

```
SELECT D.COMPANY_ID, C.COMPANY_ID, D.DOCUMENT_ID, D.DOCUMENT_CODE
  FROM DOCUMENTS D, 
       COMPANIES C
 WHERE D.COMPANY_ID(+) = C.COMPANY_ID
```